# How do I correct my output so that it returns the specified categories with the corresponding tickers price sums inside the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, yahoo-finance, yfinance

How do I correct my code so it categorizes my specified dictionaries ('Trash' and 'Tech').

Then add the sum of each ticker's prices of each category?

For example it would output: The string of the category following the sum of dictionary.

Trash: (sum of prices of AMC + DOGE-USD, GME)

Tech: (sum of prices of TSLA + NIO + NVDA)

```
import requests
import yfinance as yf

portfolios = {'Trash': ['AMC', 'DOGE-USD', 'GME'], 'Tech':['TSLA','NIO','NVDA']}

for tickers in portfolios:
    for tickers in portfolios[tickers]:
        info = yf.Ticker(tickers).info
        marketprice = str(info.get('regularMarketPrice'))
        message= tickers +","+ marketprice
        print(message)
        #print (portfolios)
```

Comment: `for tickers in portfolios` iterates over the keys of your `portfolios` dictionary, in this case just `"Trash"` and `"Tech"`. If you want to instead iterate over the tickers, you need to do something like `for category, ticker in portfolios.items()`. Go ahead and do that and then print `category` and `label` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your loop like this:

```
for category in portfolios:
    sum = 0
    for ticker in portfolios[category]:
        info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
        marketprice = info.get('regularMarketPrice')
        sum += marketprice
        message= ticker +","+ str(marketprice)
        print(message)
    print(category + ": " + sum)
```

Comment: That worked, how would I can I take it a step further so it would return my specified categories ticker price's sum? Like the sum of prices of tickers in the dictionary Trash?

Comment: I updated my answer to calculate the sum per category and print it. Please consider accepting my answer if it meets your needs.